# How do I perform a distinct on a column I am selecting dynamically?

Tags: linq, dynamic-linq

I am using dynamic linq and selecting a column dynamically. I need to do a distinct on this. How could I do this?

```
var qry = tbl.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()
             .Select("new(it[\"" + this.UniqueName + "\"]
             .ToString() as " + this.UniqueName + ")");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using

```
as " + this.UniqueName + "
```

do

`as someFixedColumnName`

and run your `Distinct()` clause on that, using ordinary Linq.

---

Alternatively, you could try [this extension method:](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqtosql/thread/12d18167-ce4d-4f57-85b8-ee806a514302)

```
public static IQueryable DynamicDistinct(this IQueryable source)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "Distinct",
            new Type[] { source.ElementType },
            source.Expression));
}
```

Comment: I want to use this.UniqueName because control uses that to populate the column...And I don't know the fixed name until the control renders.